# php patch method curl request send

Tags: php, curl

I need below code to php curl request to remote server. i am not able to do this and not getting source from google

curl -X PATCH 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "x-api-token: API_TOKEN" 
--header "x-api-user: API_USER"  --data '{"profile_id":"string","msg_product":["A2P","P2P"]}' 
"https://api.telnyx.com/messaging/numbers/{tn}"

Answer (score 0):

Some php equivalent could be :

using curl :

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telnyx.com/messaging/numbers/'.$tn,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"profile_id":"string","msg_product":["A2P","P2P"]}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'x-api-token: API_TOKEN',
    'x-api-user: API_USER'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

or using guzzle :

```php
<?php
$client = new Client();
$headers = [
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'x-api-token' => 'API_TOKEN',
  'x-api-user' => 'API_USER'
];
$body = '{
  "profile_id": "string",
  "msg_product": [
    "A2P",
    "P2P"
  ]
}';
$request = new Request('PATCH', 'https://api.telnyx.com/messaging/numbers/'.$tn, $headers, $body);
$res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
echo $res->getBody();
```

Comment: how can solve this error ? GuzzleHttp\Client::sendAsync(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface

Comment: You are using the wrong request i guess, it's this one : `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`